# Can the Snorlax you find on route 7 in pokemon X/Y be shiny?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I am playing pokemon x and have reseted it many times, but the Snorlax on route 7 was never shiny. Can the Snorlax on route 7 be shiny or do I have to breed?

Comment: I can't tell if you understand how rare shiny pokemon are. The probability of a pokemon being shiny is about 1 in 8000, so you would have to reset the game hundreds if not thousands of times to have even a good chance of that particular pokemon being shiny.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it can be shiny. Every pokemon generated has a 1 in 8172 chance of being shiny. The odds are VERY against you for any one-chance pokemon like Snorlax and the starters. You are much better off either resetting until it is female or just getting it male and getting a different language Ditto and breed for a Shiny using the [Masuda Method](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Masuda_method).

Comment: This statement is not entirely true. As of Gen V, certain Pokemon were not coded to be available as shiny Pokemon. Victini, Reshiram and Zekrom to name a couple. http://www.serebii.net/games/shiny.shtml